# How do I make current menu item active in mvc 4 .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i want open the li in plugin while click a page and glow that page using mvc ...

Here is my treeview view page code:

```
@helper GetTreeView(Abacus_CMS.Models.AbacusModel siteMenu, int parentID)
{
var url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(Context.Request.RequestContext);
foreach (var i in siteMenu.AbacusMenuList.Where(a => a.ParentCatagoryId.Equals(parentID)))
{
        <li>
            @{ var submenu = siteMenu.AbacusMenuList.Where(a => a.ParentCatagoryId.Equals(i.Id)).Count();}
            @if (submenu > 0)
            {
                <li style="margin-left: -6px;">
                <a href="@url.RouteUrl("GettingStarted", new { catname = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(i.Name.Replace(' ', '-'))})" id="@i.Name.Replace(' ', '-').ToLower()">

                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"style="margin-left: 25px; font-size: 10px;"> 
                    </i><span class="title" style="margin-left: 0px;">@i.Name</span>
                    <span class="arrow " style="height: 4px;"></span>

                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    @treeview.GetTreeView(siteMenu, i.Id)
                    @* Recursive  Call for Populate Sub items here*@
                </ul>
            </li>
            }
            else
            {
                <img src="\Content\img\icon-round.jpg.jpg" style="margin-left:25px;margin-top:1px;position:relative;width: 5px;height: 5px;">
                <a href="@url.RouteUrl("GettingStarted", new { catname = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(i.Name.Replace(' ', '-')) })" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top:-20px;padding-bottom:15px" id="@i.Name.Replace(' ', '-').ToLower()">                
                        @i.Name
                    </a>
             }
           </li>

}
```

Here i am calling the treeview:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.AbacusMenuList.Count > 0)
{
    <ul class="page-sidebar-menu " data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">


        @treeview.GetTreeView(Model, Model.ParentCatagoryId)
    </ul>
}
```

All the name are dynamically coming into my plugins..
here i want when i click the page respectively that plugin need to open..